# React-Bootstrap Import NavBar module

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, create-react-app

I am trying to recreate some code from the React-Bootstrap documentation in my Reat project (bootstrapped with create-react-app).

But I have a problem with these Boostrap "sub-components" like  `NavBar.Header`

This my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {NavBar, Nav, NavItem} from 'react-bootstrap';

class MainNav extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar>
        <Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Brand>
            <a href="#">React-Bootstrap</a>
          </Navbar.Brand>
        </Navbar.Header>
        <Nav>
          <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Link</NavItem>
          <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Link</NavItem>
          <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-    dropdown">
            <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Action</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem eventKey={3.2}>Another action</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Something else here</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem divider />
            <MenuItem eventKey={3.4}>Separated link</MenuItem>
          </NavDropdown>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar>
    )
  }
}

export default MainNav;
```

I get the following console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Header' of undefined
    at MainNav.render (MainNav.js:15)
    at ReactCompositeComponent.js:796
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:75)
    at     ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext     (ReactCompositeComponent.js:795)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent     (ReactCompositeComponent.js:822)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:362)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent     (ReactCompositeComponent.js:258)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:46)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:238)
    at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (ReactDOMComponent.js:697)
```

I found this article, which seems to explain the issue:
http://www.ericfeminella.com/blog/2016/08/12/react-bootstrap-es6-imports/

But the solution does not work for me. When I try to import directly from the `/lib/NavBar` directory, I get a compile error:

```
Error in ./src/container/blocks/MainNav.js
Module not found: 'react-bootstrap/lib/NavBar' in /homefolder/project/src/containers/blocks
```

Can anybody help me with his?

Comment: Javascript variables are case-sensitive. You imported it as `NavBar` but use it as `Navbar`.

Comment: Sometimes, I should have someone behind me to know me over the head when I get stuck. I might have spent just about 3 to 4 hours on this..

THANK YOU! @Chris ! :-)

Comment: Happens. I marked the question to be closed since it's only a typographical error.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are two main issues I can see in your code:

1. **Typo**: You are using Bootstrap's ***Navbar*** component but trying to ***import*** the component as Nav**B**ar; Notice the uppercase "B" in the import.
2. **Imports**: Every component that you intend to use needs to be imported. You are missing ***NavDropdown*** and ***MenuItem***.

Your imports should look like the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem, NavDropdown, MenuItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Once that is corrected your component will run.

Comment: OMG, thank you so much Mauricio for pointing out this subtle error! NarBar somehow had been working on my local env but not happy in CI.

Answer (score 2):

you also can use material: mdbootstrap
https://github.com/mdbootstrap/bootstrap-material-design

```
npm install mdbootstrap
```

navbar to implement:
https://mdbootstrap.com/react/components/navbar/

below exemple of navebar file component NavbarFeatures.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, NavbarBrand, NavbarNav, NavbarToggler, Collapse, NavItem, NavLink, Dropdown, DropdownToggle, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem } from 'mdbreact';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

class NavbarFeatures extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            collapse: false,
            isWideEnough: false,
            dropdownOpen: false
        };
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    }

    onClick(){
        this.setState({
            collapse: !this.state.collapse,
        });
    }

    toggle() {
        this.setState({
            dropdownOpen: !this.state.dropdownOpen
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Navbar color="indigo" dark expand="md" scrolling>
                    <NavbarBrand href="/">
                        <strong>Navbar</strong>
                    </NavbarBrand>
                    { !this.state.isWideEnough && <NavbarToggler onClick = { this.onClick } />}
                    <Collapse isOpen = { this.state.collapse } navbar>
                        <NavbarNav left>
                          <NavItem active>
                              <NavLink to="#">Home</NavLink>
                          </NavItem>
                          <NavItem>
                              <NavLink to="#">Features</NavLink>
                          </NavItem>
                          <NavItem>
                              <NavLink to="#">Pricing</NavLink>
                          </NavItem>
                          <NavItem>
                              <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle}>
                              <DropdownToggle nav caret>Dropdown</DropdownToggle>
                              <DropdownMenu>
                                  <DropdownItem href="#">Action</DropdownItem>
                                  <DropdownItem href="#">Another Action</DropdownItem>
                                  <DropdownItem href="#">Something else here</DropdownItem>
                                  <DropdownItem href="#">Something else here</DropdownItem>
                              </DropdownMenu>
                              </Dropdown>
                          </NavItem>
                        </NavbarNav>
                        <NavbarNav right>
                          <NavItem>
                            <form className="form-inline md-form mt-0">
                              <input className="form-control mr-sm-2 mb-0 text-white" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"/>
                            </form>
                          </NavItem>
                        </NavbarNav>
                    </Collapse>
                </Navbar>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

You can load on CDNJS with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.4.5/css/mdb.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.4.5/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
```